# Seamless textures over joined plains

Tags: texturing

I'm close to super beginner with Blender.

Context: I'm trying to create a 3D floor map of my apartment. So far so good, but I have a problem with textures.

Let's say I want to create the floor for the kitchen. The shape is not a perfect rectangle so I overlap 2 planes, then join them, and I get a single flat shape. Fine.

When I then try to add the chosen texture, a seamless tile textures, it gets warped and stretched in funky ways.
I just want the texture to fill the shape I create (whatever the flat shape) and be forever seamless whatever the size of the shape. Like a bucket filling so to say.

Any easy way to do that? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer will lie in how your plane (floor) is UV unwrapped, i.e. what does it's UV Map look like. With your floor in Edit mode, open a UV Editor window and see how the UV Map is overlaid over your texture -  it will probably explain the warping and stretching. Also see if you can clean up your topology after joining those two floor planes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into it, I still have to look into UV mapping (I'm following an online class).I honestly thought to be more straight forward but it shouldn't be impossible :)

Comment: "The shape is not a perfect rectangle so I overlap 2 planes, then join them, and I get a single flat shape." This part troubles me. If you're doing a floor, one plane should be sufficient. Why create more than one plane and join them? That's almost certainly going to create UV weirdness, which as Justin suggests, is likely the issue.

Comment: I understand your point but it's the only way I know. It's a floor but kinda "L" shaped. I also tried starting with a plane (square) then divide it and estrude it to shape, but had the same weird result after applying the texture. Would you suggest me the right way to do what I need? thanks.